# How do I Set a Property value to an URL Parameter when adding a document to a library

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint page that has a document library where individuals will be adding documents typically by dragNDrop but sometimes using the "Add a document" option.  I want to default one of the document properties to the value that is in the URL Parameter.

I have not tried anything yet.  I have no clue how I would do this.  I understand that it will probably be JavaScript

The URL for this page will be like

```
...SitePages/Project.aspx?Name=Project%20Sample.
```

Where everything on this page is filtered by the URL parameter.  When the user adds a document (either by dragNDrop or by "Add a document"), the document property **Name** will be set to "Project Sample".

Answer (score 0):

You need do this by custom JavaScript logic.

Use js library such [dropzonejs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation) to upload files by drag and drop.

Read url parameter and upload&update the file to SharePoint.

You could check official demo to upload&update file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery#code-example-1-upload-a-file-across-sharepoint-domains-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery